# Copy Dynamically generated filename and paste it in an other Folder

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I am held up with one of the task I need to perform to create CSV file with its name generated in run time and then Copy that same file and paste it to a different folder. I'm able to create the required file.
Here is what I've done till now:

1. In SSIS I'm taking a DFT in control flow and taking a view as my
   OLEDB source, then pointing it to a Flat File destination and
   creating a file in my desired location say folder x in a variable
   i.e **My_dest_folder** for the variable I've created. Here are the steps I've followed.
2. **My_dest_folder** of type string and have given my folders path as the value.
3. **Filename** of type sting and gave a name say cv99351_ as the value.
4. **Timestamp** of type string and give the expression which generates a timestamp  YYYYMMDDHHMISS format.
5. **Archivefolder** of type sting and gave another path where the generated file is supposed to be copied from **My_dest_folder** &
   pasted into
       archive folder.
6. In the connection string of my flat file connection manager, I have given the variables with
   @My_dest_folder+@Filename+@Timestamp+".csv". which creates a file
   with name cs99351_.csv in the folder x.

After the file is created I am trying to capture the filename from the **My_dest_folder** but since the timestamp also contains seconds I am not able to capture it everytime.
Can someone please help me out here? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Don't you already have the filename? you already created it

Answer (score 0):

If someone want to save his files with SSIS, your description is already nice and could be use as a tutorial :)

But if I understand well you have a problem at the end of your process, when you try to get the filename generated.
To read it you use the same variable concatenation but sometimes your Timestamp can change and then you get an error (Your file doesn't exist)

If yes, I guess that you use a kind of GETDATE() function in the expression of your variable. It appears that SSIS will evalute the value of your variable each time you will request it.

I tested it:
I Ran 3 Insert statement and wait with the debugger between each.
[image]

It gave me 3 differents values:

[image]

I recommend you to not use your getdate() function in the variable expression.
You can retrieve it with a unique SQL Task (**with a SELECT GETDATE() SQL Query**) or with C# / VB method.

Does it solve your problem?

Regards,

Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

1. There was a specific named file in the source folder.

   ```
    @[User::v_Orig_FileName] : @[$Project::v_FilePath]+ @[$Project::v_FileName]
   ```
2. It was renamed with the timestamp using GETDATE()

   ```
    @[User::v_Archive_FileName] : @[$Project::v_FilePath] +"\\"+REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE( @[$Project::v_FileName] , ".csv", Substring((DT_WSTR,50) GETDATE(),1,19)+".csv" ),":","")," ","_")
   ```

   **Source Variable**

   ```
    @[User::v_Orig_FileName]
   ```

   **Destination Variable**

   ```
    @[User::v_Archive_FileName]
   ```
3. The file was moved into the archive folder. To get the source file name , I was using the exactly same variable name as the destination variable name in step 2.

   ```
    @[User::v_Archive_Folder]: @[$Project::v_FilePath]+ "\\Archive"

    @[User::v_Archive_ArchivedFileName] :  @[User::v_Archive_Folder] +"\\"+REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE( @[$Project::v_FileName] , ".csv", Substring((DT_WSTR,50) GETDATE(),1,19)+".csv" ),":","")," ","_")
   ```

   **Source Variable**

   ```
    @[User::v_Archive_FileName]
   ```

   **Destination Variable**

   ```
   @[User::v_Archive_ArchivedFileName]
   ```

If the timestamp for step 2 and step 3 has even a second difference, there is an error as, pointed out above, that GETDATE() will evaluate each time when it is requested.

So the solution I came up with was swapping the Step 2 and Step 3.

1. There was a specific named file in the source folder.

   ```
    @[User::v_Orig_FileName] : @[$Project::v_FilePath]+ @[$Project::v_FileName]
   ```
2. The file was moved into the archive folder.

   ```
     @[User::v_Archive_Folder]: @[$Project::v_FilePath]+ "\\Archive"

     @[User::v_Archive_OrigFileName] :  @[User::v_Archive_Folder] +"\\"+ @[$Project::v_FileName]
   ```

   **Source Variable**

   ```
    @[User::v_Orig_FileName]
   ```

   **Destination Variable**

   ```
    @[User::v_Archive_OrigFileName]
   ```
3. It was renamed with the timestamp using GETDATE()

   ```
    @[User::v_Archive_FileName] : @[User::v_Archive_Folder] +"\\"+REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE( @[$Project::v_FileName] , ".csv", Substring((DT_WSTR,50) GETDATE(),1,19)+".csv" ),":","")," ","_")
   ```

   **Source Variable**

   ```
   @[User::v_Archive_OrigFileName]
   ```

   **Destination Variable**

   ```
   @[User::v_Archive_FileName]
   ```

Hope this gives an idea to have a different spin on this issue.